# Is there an open-source alternative for the FF Netto font?

Tags: font-recommendation

Basically, the title of the question already says it all: Is there an open-source alternative to FF Netto?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could do with more explanation as to what you're really looking for. Typewriter-esque? Roundedness? No stroke contrast? High x-height? Lining figures, i.e. all numbers are same height? There are many aspects to a font and we have no clue which ones you want.

Also, you ask for open source, but I have a hunch what you're looking for is actually free (as in money and licencing) instead of with access to sourcecode. In which case; have a look at this selection over at [fontsquirrel.com](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/find_fonts?filter%5Bclassifications%5D%5B0%5D=sans%20serif&filter%5Btags%5D%5B0%5D=rounded). That site only lists fonts which are okay to use for free, in commercial projects.

Answer (score 1):

FF Netto is available as a web font as part of an Adobe CC type kit subscription. If you're looking for a free alternative, as suggested by PixelSnader, you could try [Ropa Sans](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Ropa+Sans) or [Exo 2](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Exo+2) on Google Fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Varela Round on Google Fonts has a comparable look and feel.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Graphic Design StackExchange. We hope you enjoy your stay and share information on the site. It would be helpful to see a sample of your recommendation and what you imply is comparable look and feel. Anything you can add will be of greater help and a better answer.